# Firebase functions with typescript and auth

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to implement firebase functions using typescript. So far I was able to create some functions without problem until I had to deal with authentication.
This is my first time using typescript, so I may be asking something that is obvious for most of the developers.

Context:

I was able to implement authentication check using this [example](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/authenticated-json-api/functions/index.js).
As we can see in that example (javascript) the code is decoding the token and passing the user information to the request, which will be processed by the next function.

Problem:

My problem is that I do not know how to do that in typescript.
First of all, I had to add some types to the parameters in my token validator functions as the compiler was complaining about not having a type (like in the javascript example), so I went for something like this:

```
const validateFirebaseIdToken = async (req: any, res: any, next: any)
```

The problem is that in my next function I am not able to get the user:

```
example.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  req.user
}
```

I receive the error: Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Request < Dictionary< string>>'.

so, how would you do it in this case? I do not want to decode the token again in the second function because it wouldn't make sense (I already did that in the previous step (token validation)).

Ideally:

- I would like to use the same approach as it is in the javascript example.
- I would like to add the right type to the parameters in the toke validation function. I tried using Request < Dictionary< String>> butthe compiler complains saying that that type is not generic (I deduced the type from the second function)

This is my code:

```
const validateFirebaseIdToken = async (req: any, res: any, next: any) => {}

const example = express();
example.use(validateFirebaseIdToken);
example.get('/', async (req, res) => {}
```

Comment: How does the request look like, that you send to your function?

Comment: @ConstantinBeer do you mean the request from the client? if that is so, then it is like a normal http request with the token to authenticate. So far the authentication is working without problem. I just need to do some operations related to the user that is making those requests. That is why I need to get the user information in my second function.

Comment: Try to use req.body.user

Comment: Typescript is just a super class of javascript, so if there's anything you're in doubt with 'typescript-wise' you can still just write and run javascript (small tip)

Comment: Hi @chrismclarke. Thanks for the tip. I just want to try to keep using typescript's features like static typing which is the reason why I decided to move from javascript to this language.

Comment: @ConstantinBeer your suggestion worked for me. Do you want to add a proper answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Glad it helped :) Yes. I will do it in a sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request includes a `body` that holds your `user`. So you have to do it like this:

```
example.get('/', async (req, res) => {
     req.body.user
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something to add to the accepted answer given by @Constantin:

Ideally:

- I would like to use the same approach as it is in the javascript example.

Besides the answer given by Constantin, I needed to add a type to the request.

> req: express.Request

- I would like to add the right type to the parameters in the toke validation function. I tried using Request< Dictionary < String>> but the compiler complains saying that that type is not generic (I deduced the type from the second function)

I ended up having this method:

```
const validateFirebaseIdToken = async (req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next: any) => {}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the recommended way to achieve this is using **Declaration merging** as stated [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/4bc49b8a36f58d82c3ce4d208f21ece3ad2586b6/types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts#L17).

1. Create a **type.d.ts** file in the `src` folder with the following code:

```js
import { auth } from "firebase-admin";

declare global {
  namespace Express {
    export interface Request {
      user: auth.DecodedIdToken;
    }
  }
}
```

By using **Declaration merging** and specifying the type for the user prop you will get autocomplete support.

2. Optionally, if you want to be very strict with the types, instead of using `express.Request` do the following:

```js
import * as expressTypes from "express-serve-static-core";

const validateFirebaseIdToken = async (
  req: expressTypes.Request<expressTypes.Dictionary<string>>,
  res: expressTypes.Response,
  next: expressTypes.NextFunction
) => {};
```